# How group has access for something?

Tags: permissions, group

Example:

In Debian if user want to have access to `journalctl` without using root credentialas he must be added to `systemd-journal` group. `/bin/journalctl` is owned by `root` and group `root` so how it works ? How `systemd-journal` group has access and how to edit this permissions. I am not talking about permisisons to files and folders but maybe it comes down to that.

Comment: What is the permission on `/var/log/journal/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program runs as the user and group(s) that invoke it. The ownership of the program executable file is irrelevant. (The exception is if the executable file has the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or setgid bit set, but this only concerns a few programs which run with elevated privileges, of which `journalctl` is not one.)

Anybody can run `/bin/journalctl`, just like anybody can run `/bin/ls`. However, not everybody can run `/bin/journalctl` *usefully*: you need to have access to the files that journalctl accesses, just like running `ls somedirectory` requires the permission to access `somedirectory`.

In the case of journalctl, the relevant files are under `/var/log/journal`. See [Where is “journalctl” data stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864722/where-is-journalctl-data-stored) for more details.

You should not change the permissions of any of the files involved. Since you don't know exactly what you're doing, you're likely to break something. If you want to give a user read access to the logs, add them to the `systemd-journal` group, that's what it's for.